# How to create a new branch with the code of another?

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I ended developing a branch, and I want to download the code from the develop branch to create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

First, checkout your source branch.

`git checkout <branch>`

Then, branch from there.

`git checkout -b <new_feature_branch>`

Take a look at [Roger Dudler Git Guide](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) for some simple git tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fork a new branch from an existing one, first checkout the existing branch and then run `git checkout -b new_branch_name` to create the new branch and also checkout the new branch.